# Function to do decryption

Tags: c++, function

I need help with function `string decryptedpassword()` which is a part of a program to decrypt a password. I have to utilize `const VOWELS` to identify presence of vowels and insert 0 before and e after each vowel dynamically.
The main goal of program is to make an authentication system that begin with  some initial arguments containing his or her credentials to be validated by the program.
These arguments are stated in the command line and should consist of two values, one for `username` and the other for `password`. Fortunately, the client has already specified that Kalle will use the following credentials:

```
Username: Kalle  

Password: bAnanASplit
```

These arguments are passed to `main(..)` which in turn hands them over to `mainArgumentsParser(..)`, a function devoted to the process of parsing out values. You are free to study how this is done but may not modify any of the code you find in these functions. The parser will return a string value containing user
credentials in the form `username,password`, or simply ”`fail`” to inform `main(..)` that too few arguments were provided.
The string of credentials are then passed to `authenticateUser(..)` which will need to separate the `username` from `password` and store them in separate strings. As can be seen in the function definition, there already exists two string constants. 
`const string USERNAME = "Kalle"`;

```
const string PASSWORD = "i0J0u0j0u0J0Zys0r0{";
```

```cpp
#include "Prototypes.h"
using std::string;
using std::stringstream;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
// If argument less than 3 so print fail.
string mainArgumentParser(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc < 3)
        return "fail";
    std::stringstream ss;
   ss << argv[1] << "," << argv[2];
    return ss.str();
}
//bool function to separate username and password and validate them.
bool authenticateUser(string value)
{
    const string USERNAME = "Kalle";
    const string PASSWORD = "i0J0u0j0u0J0Zys0r0{";
    bool authPassed = false;

    string username = value.substr(0, 5);
    size_t pos = value.find(",");
    string pass = value.substr(pos + 1);

    if (username == USERNAME && decryptPassword(pass) == PASSWORD )
    {
        authPassed = true;
    }
    return authPassed;
}
// bool to detremine if the number is even or not.
bool even(int x)
{
    return  x % 2 == 0;

}
//function to decrypt the paasword and return the result to validate the authentication.

string decryptPassword(string password)
{
    const int ROT7 = 7, ROT9 = 9;
    const string VOWELS = "AEIOUYaeiouy";
    string decryptedpass;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < password.length(); i++) {
        if (even(i)) {
            decryptedpass += password[i] + ROT7;
        }
        else {
            decryptedpass += password[i] + ROT9;
        }
        decryptedpass += '0';
    }   
  return decryptedpass;
}
```

Comment: What does "insert 0" mean? What are you trying to do? Where does your program fail? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs?

Comment: You described what you try to do. But what is your question? Does it not work?

Comment: The code you show seems completely unrelated to the goal you describe. Please explain  the relevance of the shown code for the described goal.

Comment: Inser 0 means that I have to insert 0 before and after each vowels. As I wrote that a function is a part of aprogram to do decryption of password. I should enter bAnanASplit as first argument and when the program is done i should get "i0J0u0j0u0J0Zys0r0{".

Comment: Please [edit] to explain.

Comment: If somebody asks what you mean by a specific expression, then quoting that expression with more words around it exactly as it already occurs in the question does not really help. You'd better try to rephrase and explain the same thing with other words. Giving an example helps, but being able to rephrase a goal is an important ability to demonstrate that you yourself understand it. Otherwise you risk the impression that you are basically quoting from an assignment you did not really understand.

Comment: I have edited my post. Sorry if it was unclear but i wrote the part which I need help with.